# How To Extract Frames From a Video Using C/C++

Tags: video, mp4, frames

I have a problem about extracting frames from a video file (mp4, avi) 
How can I do that in my program by using C or C++ ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Easy way [opencv](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/highgui_reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html) hard way [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/)

Comment: thank you, Martin Beckett.
I'm working on VLC media player and using gcc compiler. 
So, is there any other way to do so ?

Comment: @flying_coder - do you need to do it in code? The very easy way is to use the ffmpeg executable on the commandline to extra a frame as an image. You could even control thsi from your own app with a system() call and then read the temp image

Comment: yes, i want to do it in code.  But, I'm working on VLC media player and using gcc compiler. So, I don't think ffmpeg would give me the solution. Can you please suggest me any other way?

Comment: ffmpeg is pretty easy to build/use on Linux with gcc. It's much harder on windows. But vlc uses it's own libs - you have the source!

Comment: You can IIRC remote control VLC from another program over a network, that could be a good solution

Comment: I do have the source code of VLC. But I'm not getting the "frames" part.  
I want to add a functionality that will provide previews of video frames while running a video in VLC. Same as the functionality that has been added recently by Youtube. Can you please direct me ?

Comment: "You can IIRC remote control VLC from another program over a network", can you please explain me this in brief ?

Comment: http://n0tablog.wordpress.com/2009/02/09/controlling-vlc-via-rc-remote-control-interface-using-a-unix-domain-socket-and-no-programming/  and  http://www.videolan.org/doc/play-howto/en/ch04.html

Answer (score 1):

Use ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 img%04d.jpg -hide_banner
```

For more details see [here](http://www.bugcodemaster.com/article/extract-images-frame-frame-video-file-using-ffmpeg).